# Filling a matrix to plot it with plt.imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have got following plan of the house and I want to represent it as a matrix in Python:

[image: plan of the house]

I thought about matrix with values like that:

Blank space - 0, Rooms - 1, Walls - 2

Then I'd like to plot this with plot.imshow().

I've already got this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Dom:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params
        matrices = {}
        self.matrices = matrices
        for key in params["indexes"].keys():
            row_min = min([tup[0] for tup in params["indexes"][key]])
            row_max = max([tup[0] for tup in params["indexes"][key]])
            col_min = min([tup[1] for tup in params["indexes"][key]])
            col_max = max([tup[1] for tup in params["indexes"][key]])
            self.matrices[key] = np.zeros((row_max - row_min, col_max - col_min))
            mask = params["mask"][key]
            self.matrices[key][mask == 1] = 1
            mask = params["mask"][key]
            self.matrices[key][mask == 1] = 1

        self.bigmatrix = np.zeros((100, 100))
        for key in params["indexes"].keys():
            row_min = min([tup[0] for tup in params["indexes"][key]])
            row_max = max([tup[0] for tup in params["indexes"][key]])
            col_min = min([tup[1] for tup in params["indexes"][key]])
            col_max = max([tup[1] for tup in params["indexes"][key]])

            self.bigmatrix[row_min:row_max, col_min:col_max] = self.matrices[key]


    def build(self):
        return self.matrices.values()

    def build2(self):
        return self.bigmatrix


if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = {"indexes": {"I": [(0, 0), (0, 50), (50, 0), (50, 50)],
                          "II": [(0, 50), (0, 100), (50,50), (50, 100)],
                          "III": [(50, 0), (50, 100), (70, 0), (70, 100)],
                          "IV": [(70, 0), (70,50), (100,0), (100,50)],
                          "V": [(70,50), (70,100), (100,50), (100, 100)]},
              "rozdzielczosc": {},
              "mask": {"I": 1, "II": 0, "III": 1, "IV": 1, "V": 1},
              "wall":{"I":[(0,49), (0,50), (50,49), (50,50)]}}

    dom = Dom(params)
    print(dom.build2())
    plt.imshow(dom.build2())
    plt.show()
```

Which gives me following (good) results:

[image: result from code]

But I would like to add the walls to the house, one unit of width (so insert values of 2 in specific coordinates in matrix) but I don't have any idea how to do this. I tried something like that:

```
        for key in params["wall"].keys():
            w_row_min = min([tup[0] for tup in params["wall"][key]])
            w_row_max = max([tup[0] for tup in params["wall"][key]])
            w_col_min = min([tup[1] for tup in params["wall"][key]])
            w_col_max = max([tup[1] for tup in params["wall"][key]])
            self.matrices[key][w_row_max - w_row_min, w_col_max - w_col_min] = 2

#I added this example line to params dict: wall":{"I":[(0,49), (0,50), (50,49), (50,50)]}}
```

But it doesn't work at all and I don't know how to do it in another way.
I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could potentially be better served by using matplotlib's `plot` (docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), for creating walls) and `Rectangle` (docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html), for creating rooms), what you're writing seems like you're trying to re-implement some of these functions with imshow.

Perhaps something like this?

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

rooms = [[(0, 0), (0, 50), (50, 0), (50, 50)],
         [(0, 50), (0, 100), (50,50), (50, 100)],
         [(50, 0), (50, 100), (70, 0), (70, 100)],
         [(70, 0), (70,50), (100,0), (100,50)],
         [(70,50), (70,100), (100,50), (100, 100)]]
masks = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

for room, show in zip(rooms, masks):
    row_min = min(room, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]
    row_max = max(room, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]
    col_min = min(room, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
    col_max = max(room, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]

    print(row_min, row_max, col_min, col_max)
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((row_min, col_min), row_max - row_min, col_max - col_min, fill=True,
                           facecolor="yellow" if show else "purple", edgecolor='black', lw=2))

ax.set(xlim=(-10, 110), ylim=(-10, 110))
plt.show()
```

You'll need to fix the coordinates to be the transpose but I think this does what you need. Then you can just change `lw` to change how thick to make the walls.

Alternatively you can set `lw=0` and use `plot` to add walls wherever you like.

Hope this helps!